# How to access attributes of object sent to controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a trivial question but even after 2 days checking on stackoverflow I haven't found a solution.

When I forward the params to read a record from a database all works - but I found no way to access the parameters directly creating a view object or a columns array.

I receive following post request in my rails controller:

```
Started POST "/views/update" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-07 17:27:51 +0400
Processing by ViewsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {
    "view"=>{
      "id"=>1, 
      "name"=>"All Opportunties", 
      "columns"=>[
        {
          "id"=>1, 
          "label"=>"Name", 
          "fieldNameOrPath"=>"name", 
          "typ"=>"link", 
          "linkp"=>"id", 
          "link"=>"/opportunities/proposal/general", 
          "entity_id"=>1, 
          "hidden"=>true, 
          "created_at"=>"2017-08-06T22:12:03.000Z", 
          "updated_at"=>"2017-08-06T22:12:03.000Z"
        }, 
        {
          "id"=>2, 
          "label"=>"Account", 
          "fieldNameOrPath"=>"account.name", 
          "typ"=>"link", "linkp"=>"account_id", 
          "link"=>"/accounts", 
          "entity_id"=>1, 
          "hidden"=>false, 
          "created_at"=>"2017-08-06T22:12:03.000Z", 
          "updated_at"=>"2017-08-06T22:12:03.000Z"
        },
        {
          "id"=>3, 
          "label"=>"Owner", 
          "fieldNameOrPath"=>"user.username", 
          "typ"=>"string", 
          "linkp"=>nil, 
          "link"=>nil, 
          "entity_id"=>1, 
          "hidden"=>false, 
          "created_at"=>"2017-08-06T22:12:03.000Z", 
          "updated_at"=>"2017-08-06T22:12:03.000Z"
        },
        {
          "id"=>4, 
          "label"=>"Close Date", 
          "fieldNameOrPath"=>"closedate", 
          "typ"=>"datetime", 
          "linkp"=>nil, 
          "link"=>nil, 
          "entity_id"=>1, 
          "hidden"=>false, 
          "created_at"=>"2017-08-06T22:12:03.000Z", 
          "updated_at"=>"2017-08-06T22:12:03.000Z"
          }, 
          {
            "id"=>5, 
            "label"=>"Stage", 
            "fieldNameOrPath"=>"stage", 
            "typ"=>"string", 
            "linkp"=>nil, 
            "link"=>nil, 
            "entity_id"=>1, 
            "hidden"=>false, 
            "created_at"=>"2017-08-06T22:12:03.000Z", 
            "updated_at"=>"2017-08-06T22:12:03.000Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Ideally I want to have the received parameter in an object called `view` from where I can access its attributes - specially the columns array. My object structure is:

```
View { id, name, columns [{id, label ...}] }
```

I want to loop through all columns:

```
view.columns.each do |column|
  column.name = ...
end
```

It looks to me very basic but all methods I tried to assign the params to view (or create an object for columns only) failed. Most time I get the error message `method xxx of view` unknown.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Have you tried with `params` (i.e. `params[:view]:[columns].each do |column|`)?

Comment: Have you created a model for your view? If so could you paste it please?

When you're creating objects from paramaters it's done through your controller, creating lots at once is slightly more involved, but to access them, type in params[:view] and you'll receive the json you listed

Comment: Yes - I tried. If I do this then I get following message:
NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):

Comment: Hi Mark,I havent created a model 'view' as described above since I dont want to store the view object as is in my database. I just want to loop through the columns and then do some actions based on the result.

But I have a similar controller where I have models created and it worked in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
params['view']['columns'].each do |column|
  puts column['id']
end
```

That will print in console the `id` of each `column`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Great!!!! This worked!!

I always used column.id - but column['id'] works.

Comment: Done ;-) I am also newbie on stackoverflow ;-) my times as a developer have been 20 years ago ;-)

Comment: @MichaelH. Its never late to pick it up again! Welcome! You can check the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for a quick SO introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
view = params[:view]

view[:columns].each do |column|
  column[:name] = ...
end
```

That said, this feels like code that might better fit in a model than the controller.

Comment: Hi David, tried this - doesnt work. I am getting following error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):

I didnt want to have it in a model - since I dont do any db transaction with these elements. I just do some validation etc. I am very new to rails - perhaps I dont get the point but creating a model will automartically result in creating a table isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

the parameters would be accessed via the `params` object as a Hash:

```
params['view']['id']    # 1
params['view']['name']  # All Opportunities
params['view']['columns'].first['typ']    # link
```

However, it sounds like all that you need is more like a wrapper object for the parameters in 'view'. I don't know of any specifics, offhand, for your data, but you can create simple objects, based on hash data, using [OpenStruct](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) objects.

As for the actual work of creating said object so that it is accessible in the controller, consider using a [:before_filter](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter) in your Rails Controller to create an object using the data in `params` as input.

Comment: Hi Sal, I can access each single feed like you described. But who can I loop through all columns and access their attributes within the loop?

I cannot paste my code and the log hier - not enoguh space. Answered my own posting so you can see it there

Comment: hmm...David Hempy's example code should do the trick. Offhand, I'd guess it didn't work because params might be a ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess object (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) so you can use string or symbol keys but hashes embedded inside of the params object might just be normal hashes, which will differentiate between symbols and string keys. It sounds like a shot-in-the-dark but try view['columns'].each do |column| and column['name'] = ... instead.